# bodyparser issue NodeJS express POST >" email undefined"

Tags: node.js, post, express

I am trying to store some user information in a MongoDB database.
From the front-end (AngularJS) on localhost:9000 I make a POST to the backend (express on localhost:3000)

I'm getting in the header information all the data, including the email-address.
but in the body **email is undefined??**

*Console from Node server:*

[image]

*Console from Web browser:*

[image]

I must do something wrong with the body parser?

Front-end:
registration View:

```html
<form ng-submit="submit()" name="register" class="form-signin" novalidate>
    <h1 class="form-signin-heading text-muted">Register</h1>
    <input name="email" ng-model="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus="" required>
        <p class="help-block" ng-show="register.email.$dirty && register.email.$invalid">Please enter a proper email.</p>
    <input name="password" ng-model="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input name="password_confirm" ng-model="password_confirm" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" validate-equals='password' required>

    <p class="help-block" ng-show="register.password_confirm.$dirty && register.password_confirm.$invalid">please match the password.</p>

    <button ng-disabled="register.$invalid" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Front-end controller:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .controller('RegisterCtrl', function ($scope, $http, alert) {
    $scope.submit = function() {

        var url = 'http://localhost:3000/register';
        var user = {
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password
        };


        $http.post(url, user)
            .success(function(res){
                alert('success', 'OK!', 'You are now registered');
            }) 
            .error(function(err) {
                alert('warning', 'Opps!', 'Could not register');
            });
    }
  });
```

Back-end NodeJS express server.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());      

//Verbind front-end met backend
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');

    next();
})

//MongoDB userModel
var User = mongoose.model('User', {
    email: String,
    password: String
});

//Reactie op de FRONT END POST voor REGISTRATIE
app.post('/register', function(req, res){
    //emailVerification.s end(req.user.email);
    //createSendToken(req.user, res);
    var user = req.body;
    console.log('req.body**' + req.body);
    console.log('req.headers**' +req.headers);

    var newUser = new User({
        email: user.name,
        password: user.password
    })

    newUser.save(function(err) {
        //als goed opgeslagen > send status 200 en json new user
        res.status(200).json(newUser);  
        console.log(newUser);
    });


});


//MONGODB CONNECTIE =====================================
mongoose.connect('mongodb://....');
//MONGODB CONNECTIE =====================================

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('api listening on ', server.address().port);
})
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Dot operator , Change your Template as below,(sample code)

```
    <form class="list" name="loginForm" ng-submit="login(credentials)" novalidate>
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" for="username">
            <span class="input-label">UserName</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" ng-model="credentials.username">
        </label>

        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" for="password">
            <span class="input-label">Password</span>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" ng-model="credentials.password">
        </label>

        <button class="button button-block button-dark activated" type="submit">Logga in</button>
    </form>
```

And in your Controller,

you get username as

```
var user = $scope.username;
```

Please read upon this article about **Understanding Scopes** 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ngRepeat

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

I made a typo in "Back-end NodeJS express server"

```
var newUser = new User({
        email: **user.name,**
        password: user.password
    })
```

must be:

```
var newUser = new User({
        email: **user.email,**
        password: user.password
    })
```